# setlistener: errors with jack and alsa

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, jack

Sound newbie here.
I'm trying to configure [listener](https://www.vanheusden.com/listener/) but get A LOT of [errors](https://pastebin.com/kTEWnus9).
My goal is to record sound using that tool from external usb mic which is in webcam.
So, I have headless (no `X` running) Raspberry Pi model B+ running Raspbian 10, there's no realtime priority because I was unable to set it up on this OS and to be honest I'm unsure I need it: I'm OK if the record will be a bit shifted in time.

I had set up `libsndfile` and `portaudio` as well as
`apt install -y jackd2 pulseaudio-module-jack jack-tools libasound2-dev libbjack-ocaml libbjack-ocaml-dev libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-dev`

I do see the device and was able to record sound by

`arecord -D hw:C525,0 -d 5 -f dat test.wav -c 1`

By plugging the device in and out I found that it is mapped as `/dev/media2`, `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1` (those disappear when the webcam is unplugged) so I tried to run `setlistener /dev/media2` but it fails with [errors](https://pastebin.com/kTEWnus9) (same as linked above).

I tried (to be honest not fully understand what it does):

```
[as user] pulseaudio --start
[below as root]
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket 
# the file above does exist
export DISPLAY=":0"

jackd -r -d alsa
jackdmp 1.9.12
...
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
JACK server starting in non-realtime mode
self-connect-mode is "Don't restrict self connect requests"
audio_reservation_init
dbus_bus_request_name() failed. (1)
Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : Connection ":1.23" is not allowed to own the service "org.freedesktop.ReserveDevice1.Audio0" due to security policies in the configuration file
Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Cannot initialize driver
JackServer::Open failed with -1
Failed to open server
```

`is not allowed` is confusing because I run it as root. Also tried  `jackd -r -d C525`, `jackd -r -d hw:C525` and even `jackd -r -d hw:C525,0` but these three return

```
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
Unknown driver "[the name]"
```

What am I doing wrong?
Alternatively, I'm looking for for tool which will record audio only when the sound is louder than certain level of dB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

I've never used `listener`, and your link doesn't seem to include a man page. But it says there's an ALSA version of `listener`.

So since you are running headless anyway: Remove PulseAudio, remove JACK, remove DBUS (unless you need that for something else). Download the ALSA version of `listener`, point it directly to your `hw:C525,0` device (or maybe use `plughw` instead, if you need format conversion).

This should get rid of all the trouble with PulseAudio and JACK running at the same time (bad idea in the first place), either of them hogging the actual hardware, and one of them trying to access X through funny dependencies.